# Preview web url in Text/RichtText

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I am developing an app where I need to show web page preview inside a Container. I am unable to find a correct way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the package [simple_url_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_url_preview)

**Code sample:**

```dart
final urlList = <String>['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];

Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    ...urlList.map((url) => SimpleUrlPreview(url: url)).toList(),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `plugin`  [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) for more idea see below eg.

This is **IntelUtility** **class**

```html
static launchURL(String phone) async {
    var url = phone.startsWith("http") ? phone : "http://$phone";
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

```html
GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                IntelUtility.launchURL(
                                 websiteUrl);
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "Hotel"
                                maxLines: 2,
                              ),
                            ),
```